# How can I get data inside parent component in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I have this single type in my strapi dashboard :
[image: Single Type]

I Have a component called Logo
Another component called **Links**, it contains another component called **Link**
Finally a component called **MenuButton**.

When I go to `http://localhost:1337/api/global?populate=*` I got :

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "createdAt": "2021-12-27T11:54:36.177Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-12-27T11:54:54.737Z",
      "publishedAt": "2021-12-27T11:54:54.731Z",
      "logo": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null
      },
      "navigation": {
        "id": 1 // why I don't get links here ?
      },
      "menuButton": {
        "id": 1,
        "icon": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    
  }
}
```

I Already published my content and allowed permissions for public.

My question is :

**How can I access to the `links` inside `navigation` object ?**

Answer (score 1):

See my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70510780/11483506)

Strapi 4 requires you to populate your request (see: [population documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#relation-media-fields) )

which could look like this (for level 2 population):

```
    // populate request
    const qs = require('qs')
    const query = qs.stringify(
      {
        populate: {
          Product: {
            populate: ['Image']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        encodeValuesOnly: true
      }
    )
    // get id 
    const id = yourId
    // get rquest
    const Response= await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:1337/api/[your api]/${id }/?${query}`
    )
```

Now media links should be included in your response

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve up to 5 levels deep, you can install this package `npm i strapi-plugin-populate-deep`